# Handling HttpWebResponse's very long/infinite timeout with proxy

Tags: c#, httpwebresponse

I have a HTTPS `HttpWebRequest` connection with a proxy server. The problem is that if the proxy refuses to connect for some reason (e.g. typing a wrong address), the thread stucks at `HttpWebResponse` for very long time/maybe infinite.

What I'm trying to achieve is wait 2 seconds for the proxy to execute the request and if it doesn't succeed for these 2 seconds, throw an exception and use another proxy instead.

I couldn't find any similar question whose answer to help me.

My request is below:

```
HttpWebRequest request2 = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://.../"); 
request2.Method = "GET";
request2.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;

if (proxyAddress != null)
{
    request2.Proxy = new WebProxy(proxyAddress);
}
else
{
    request2.Proxy = null;
}

request2.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.140 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.17763";

request2.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "en-US");
request2.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br");

request2.Timeout = 2000;
request2.ReadWriteTimeout = 2000;
request2.ContinueTimeout = 2000;

string result = string.Empty;
try
{
    // Timeout - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4040538/timeout-with-httpwebresponse-in-net
    using (HttpWebResponse response2 = (HttpWebResponse)request2.GetResponse())
    {
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response2.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            result = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
}
catch (WebException e)
{
    if (e.InnerException is SocketException)
    {
        // Proxy error
    }

    // Proxy error
}
```

I also ignore certificate checks with the code below:

```
ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 500;
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
ServicePointManager.DnsRefreshTimeout = -1;
ServicePointManager.EnableDnsRoundRobin = false;
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)4080;
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender2, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
```

I tried setting`DefaultConnectionLimit` to 4 because I saw that in another answer on SO but it didn't help.

[HttpWebRequest.Timeout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebrequest.timeout?view=netframework-4.7.2) on MSDN says:

> Gets or sets the time-out value in milliseconds for the GetResponse()
>   and GetRequestStream() methods.

but basically it didn't have any impact on the proxy request.

I saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14221352/machine-specific-httpwebresponse-timeout) and I'm using .NET Framework 4.5 but it surely isn't related to my machine because there is a similar application where this functionality is working just fine and I tested on a VM as well.

I have no idea what's wrong with that.

**Edit:**
I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679192/httpwebrequest-readwritetimeout-ignored-in-net-works-in-mono) on SO. It says it was a bug but that was 9 years ago, so it should probably be fixed. Didn't anyone else get this bug?

**Edit:**
Thanks to @shingo I was able to make it work but can I somehow put proper error handling?

```
private void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)asyncResult.AsyncState;

    try
    {
        using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(asyncResult))
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                RequestResult = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (WebException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }

    _manualResetEvent.Set();
}

private void TimeoutCallback(object state, bool timedOut)
{
    if (timedOut)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)state;
        if (request != null)
        {
            request.Abort();
        }
    }
}

// Usage
using (Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
}

IAsyncResult response = request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), request);

// this line implements the timeout, if there is a timeout, the callback fires and the request becomes aborted
ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject(response.AsyncWaitHandle, new WaitOrTimerCallback(TimeoutCallback), request, 2000, true);

// The response came in the allowed time. The work processing will happen in the callback function
_manualResetEvent.WaitOne();
```

All the time there is any error no matter what `EndGetResponse` pops exception `The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.`.

The old code used to handle errors properly:

```
try
{
    // Writing content because ContentLength > 0
    using (Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream())
    {
        stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
    }

    using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponseWithoutException())
    {
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            RequestResult = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
}
catch (WebException e)
{
    if (e.InnerException is SocketException)
    {
        return ResultType.ProxyError;
    }

    return ResultType.ProxyError;
}

public static class WebRequestExtensions
{
    public static WebResponse GetResponseWithoutException(this WebRequest request)
    {
        if (request == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("request");

        try
        {
            return request.GetResponse();
        }
        catch (WebException e)
        {
            if (e.Response == null)
                throw;

            return e.Response;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use asynchronous request and handle timeout manually, check the example of [Abort](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebrequest.abort?view=netframework-4.7.2) method.

Comment: Thanks but there is one problem that it doesn't handle the error codes properly. It always throws ``The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.`` when any error occurres. Any idea how could I handle this? Edited my answer btw, you can check the code.

Comment: Did you also remove the headers and UA from the code?

Comment: I have UserAgent and Headers, I just didn't paste them here.